# Redis pub/sub consumer in a websocket - broadcast to all clients (Python)

Tags: python, websocket, redis, python-asyncio, publish-subscribe

Before asking my question, I looked at the different posts here, and couldn't find either something functionnal, or that fits my needs.

Needs:
I use pub/sub mechanism to be notified when a Redis key expires
This information is broadcasted to ALL the clients connected to the WS

Actual implementation:
I have

- one script doing the pub/sub part, adding it to a custom queue
- one script reading the queue, and pushing the items to the WS clients

I'd like to have both in one, kinda like this
(I tried to keep the exemple as tiny as possible)

```py
import asyncio
import os
import redis
import websockets

CLIENTS = set()

r = redis.StrictRedis(
    host=os.environ.get("REDIS_SVC_SERVICE_HOST", '127.0.0.1'),
    port=6379,
    db=0,
    encoding='utf-8',
    decode_responses=True,
    )


async def broadcast():
    while True:
        """
        Here should be the section to receive 'msg' from Redis
        """
        # We broadcast msg to all connected clients
        await asyncio.gather(
            *[ws.send(msg) for ws in CLIENTS],
            return_exceptions=False,
            )
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


async def handler(websocket, path):
    CLIENTS.add(websocket)
    print('[loop] >> Client')

    # Main loop
    try:
        # Receiving messages
        async for msg in websocket:
            pass  # We do nothing if we receive a msg through WS
    except websockets.ConnectionClosedError:
        print('[loop] XX Client')
    finally:
        # At the end, we remove the connection
        CLIENTS.remove(websocket)

try:
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.create_task(broadcast())
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Opening Queue
try:
    start_server = websockets.serve(handler, '0.0.0.0', 5000)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)

# Looping to daemonize the Queue
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('[core] Exiting')
```

This code exemple works, if I use `msg = 'foobar'`, every client receives 'foobar' at every loop

But if I use pubsub mechanism in the broadcast function, it doesn't work:

```py
pubsub = r.pubsub()
pubsub.psubscribe('*')

async def broadcast():
    while True:
        for msg in pubsub.listen():
            await asyncio.gather(
                *[ws.send(msg) for ws in CLIENTS],
                return_exceptions=False,
                )

        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

I have the impression it's tied to the asyncio mechanism involved here, but I can't find the right way to do it